# How to detect when a Sharepoint file is in a subfolder

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I'm displaying files from a Sharepoint 2010 document library on my web page.  I'm successfully showing a list of the files and their icons.  However, some of the files are in subfolders, and instead of showing the file icon, I'd like to show a folder icon.

**How do I detect when a file is in a subfolder?**

I could parse each file's ServerRelativeUrl to determine the folder structure.  I'm hoping there is another way.

---

Here is the Sharepoint library:

[image: library]

---

And here is the code which produces the list of files in that library:

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(SharepointSite))
    {
        var query = new CamlQuery
        {
            ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>" +
                        "<Query>" +
                         "<Where>" +
                            "<Eq>" +
                               "<FieldRef Name='FSObjType' />" +
                               "<Value Type='Integer'>0</Value>" +
                            "</Eq>" +
                         "</Where>" +
                        "</Query>" +
                      "</View>"
        };

        var sourceList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Test Library");
        var files = sourceList.GetItems(query);
        clientContext.Load(files);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var id = file.Id;
            var filename = file["FileLeafRef"].ToString();
            var iconName = clientContext.Web.MapToIcon(filename, string.Empty, IconSize.Size16);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            var imgUrl = "http://sharepointsite/_layouts/images/" + iconName.Value;
            Image iconImage = new Image {ImageUrl = imgUrl};

            clientContext.Load(file.ParentList);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            var listUrl = file.ParentList.DefaultDisplayFormUrl;
            HyperLink docLink = new HyperLink
            {
                Text = filename,
                NavigateUrl = listUrl + "?ID=" + id //ToDo:  fix
            };

            HtmlTableRow row = new HtmlTableRow();
            HtmlTableCell cell1 = new HtmlTableCell();
            cell1.Controls.Add(iconImage);
            HtmlTableCell cell2 = new HtmlTableCell();
            cell2.Controls.Add(docLink);
            row.Cells.Add(cell1);
            row.Cells.Add(cell2);
            tbFiles.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }
```

---

which results in:

[image: files]

Only the first file in the list is actually in the top-most library.  The rest are in "Test Folder".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might helpful to understand the available options for the [view scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spviewscope.aspx) property of your CAML query:

- **Default**: Gets files and subfolders from a specific folder
- **RecursiveAll**: Gets files and subfolders from all folders
- **FilesOnly**: Gets only files (no folders) from a specific folder
- **Recursive**: Gets only files (no folders) from all folders

If you want to maintain a hierarchical folder structure, you have two options:

1. Get all files in the library (using a view scope of **Recursive** or **RecursiveAll**) and try to reconstruct the file structure yourself by post-processing the results
2. Get only files and folders from one folder at a time (using a view scope of **Default**), executing a new query whenever you want to drill down into the contents of a subfolder

Both approaches are equally valid, but in general I'd recommend the second. They both have their downsides: the first requires a larger up-front network request and more post-processing logic to assemble the hierarchy, while the second requires multiple network requests to retrieve all the data.

If taking the second approach, you can limit your CAML query to a specific folder by setting the CamlQuery's [`FolderServerRelativeUrl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.camlquery.folderserverrelativeurl.aspx) property to the URL of the desired folder. When working with the items retrieved from a specific folder, you can check their [`FileSystemObjectType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listitem.filesystemobjecttype.aspx) property to determine if they are files or folders; if they are folders you can access their `Folder` property to get the associated [folder object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.folder_members.aspx), from which you can get the `ServerRelativeUrl` property to use in your next query to get items from that folder.